# Laravel - relative path in public folder

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, path

I am using tinymce editor to upload image into my server, and I am having problem with setting to the path. In `postAcceptor.php` located in **`/public`**, it will be uploading an image into the folder **`/articles/assets/images/`** inside **`/public`**.

In `web.php`, I am using **`Route::get('/articles/{id}', function(){...})`** to display an image that was already uploaded in the server. However, the image indicates wrong source so that it cannot display the image. Its source is supposed to be:-

`localhost:8000/articles/assets/images/fragment%20life%20cycle.png`

But, actually, it indicates to:-

`localhost:8000/articles **/articles**/assets/images/fragment%20life%20cycle.png`

***`postAcceptor.php`***

```
<?php
  /*******************************************************
   * Only these origins will be allowed to upload images *
   ******************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost:8000", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $today = date("y-m-d");
  $imageFolder = "articles/assets/images/";

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
      if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
      }
    }

    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);


    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

Is there any way to solve this problem, or any clue for absoulte or relative path?

[/public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylE0t.png)

[Upload success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PHta.png)

[/articles/44 - displaying image page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzzss.png)

[image src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzPoy.png)

Comment: Where is the code for the blade.php?

Comment: @MatthewSpire there's nothing to deal with the blade because the editor, tinymce, stores html code inside textarea, and I retrieve data of textarea and save into my database. For code of postAcceptor.php, i am using this one: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/

Comment: @MatthewSpire I added postAcceptor.php. I am not sure how to give them same src for a tag, img that is enabled to work in the different two URLs

Comment: If I set $imageFolder to "/assets/images/", the image source only works under the url "localhost:8000/assets/images/...", without /article

Comment: $imageFolder = public_path('assets/images');

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-app-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel comes built with path helpers that you can use to ensure you always get the right path to where you want things to go.

Try changing

```
$imageFolder = "articles/assets/images/";
```

to

```
$imageFolder = public_path("articles/assets/images/");
```